# BizTalk 2020: obfuscate sensitive tracked data sent to application insights

Tags: biztalk, azure-application-insights, sensitive-data, biztalk-2020

I have enabled the analytics options in BizTalk Server 2020. All the data is sent to Azure Application Insights. But there is too much sensitive data like username and password that are not encrypted in the customDimensions of the send port events.

Is there a hidden option in BizTalk to obfuscate or encrypt some data context?

Comment: Are the username and password in the message payload, or are these the username & password configured on the port?

Comment: Those informations are in the send ports

Answer (score 0):

If they are out of the box adapters, then you should raise a ticket with Microsoft as there are no settings to change what is sent to Analytics except for the standard Tracking settings.

See [Send BizTalk Server tracking data to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/send-tracking-data-to-azure-application-insights-using-biztalk-server)